# Keeping RAID drives with OS as a backup while setting up SSD as the new primary drive

Tags: windows, ssd, installation, raid

I am purchasing a workstation with 4x2TB HDD in RAID 10 as the primary drive with the OS (Windows). I want to replace this setup with a 1TB NVME SSD to
speed up reading and writing to disk.

I do not have much experience working with RAID setups, and I wonder if it is
possible for me to simply add the SSD to computer as the primary drive (by modifying the BIOS boot order) and
install Windows on it, while keeping the RAID setup intact so that if
something goes awry during the SSD installation, I could revert back to having the RAID
setup as the primary drive and boot Windows just as prior to the addition of the SSD
(once I have successfully installed Windows on the SSD, I intend to
break the RAID and re-purpose the drives as storage for our other workstations).
Is this setup procedure feasible or does adding the new SSD drive somehow break
the previous RAID setup so that it is not possible to boot from
it any longer?

Comment: You'd want to update your BIOS boot order for the SSD to be first.  Then I'd temporarily disconnect your RAID system and install Windows on the SSD.  After that's complete you're done.  If not, restore the original BIOS boot order and reconnect the RAID system.

Comment: @essjae Thanks for the reply. Changing the BIOS boot order is what I meant with "primary drive", sorry for being unclear. Why would I need to disconnect the RAID system physically in addition to changing the boot order? And are you referring to disconnecting every single drive individually?

Comment: Pull the raid card, unplug the drivers, etc.  Windows will look at all your drives when you install and it some cases put a small partition (IIRC system reserved partition) on another drive even if you specify which drive you're installing too.  This would remove that chance of the SSD needing the RAID volume to boot.